# Bokeh how to handle datetime with ajax updating datasource

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, bokeh

I am playing around with an new serverless reporting system built around Bokeh and AJAX and I am running into an issue with dates and times. I have a version that streams numerical data from a cloud function to an html file generated via Bokeh. Very similar to:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.2.0/examples/howto/ajax_source.py

This has worked well but the issue complicates when adding datetimes to the equation. (specifically on the x-axis)

My plan of attack was to write the JSON file that feeds the AJAX stream from a Bokeh ColumnDataSource(df).to_json_string(). This was the preferable method as this is how the data is generally fed to bokeh objects that involve javascript components. Based on the output of the ColumnDataSource there seems to be some sort of unknown hashing or recoding of the datetime column that Bokeh seems to recognize when reading it in. This auto recognition does not work when streaming ColumnDataSource(df).to_json_string() as your AJAX source. I am assuming that this requires some extra processing on the javascript side of things but I can find no examples online as to what I should be doing for the Bokeh plot to recognize this data.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models.sources import AjaxDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

adapter = CustomJS(code="""
    //console.log(cb_data)


    const result = { 'y': cb_data.response.data["y"],'datetime': cb_data.response.data['datetime']}

    console.log(result)
    return result
""")


source=AjaxDataSource(data_url='***************',
                    polling_interval=10000*60,adapter=adapter,method='GET')

p=figure(width=1500,height=500,x_axis_type="datetime")
p.line(x='y',y='datetime,source=source,color='Orange',line_width=3)
```

Here is the JSON that AJAX refrences:

> '{"data":{"datetime":{"**ndarray**":"AACAWT20dkIAACZoPbR2QgAAzHY9tHZCAAByhT20dkIAABiUPbR2QgAAvqI9tHZCAABksT20dkIAAArAPbR2QgAAsM49tHZCAABW3T20dkIAAPzrPbR2QgAAovo9tHZCAABICT60dkIAAO4XPrR2QgAAlCY+tHZCAAA6NT60dkIAAOBDPrR2QgAAhlI+tHZCAAAsYT60dkIAANJvPrR2QgAAeH4+tHZCAAAejT60dkIAAMSbPrR2QgAAaqo+tHZCAAAQuT60dkIAALbHPrR2QgAAXNY+tHZCAAAC5T60dkIAAKjzPrR2QgAATgI/tHZC","dtype":"float64","shape":[30]},"index":{"**ndarray**":"AACAWT20dkIAACZoPbR2QgAAzHY9tHZCAAByhT20dkIAABiUPbR2QgAAvqI9tHZCAABksT20dkIAAArAPbR2QgAAsM49tHZCAABW3T20dkIAAPzrPbR2QgAAovo9tHZCAABICT60dkIAAO4XPrR2QgAAlCY+tHZCAAA6NT60dkIAAOBDPrR2QgAAhlI+tHZCAAAsYT60dkIAANJvPrR2QgAAeH4+tHZCAAAejT60dkIAAMSbPrR2QgAAaqo+tHZCAAAQuT60dkIAALbHPrR2QgAAXNY+tHZCAAAC5T60dkIAAKjzPrR2QgAATgI/tHZC","dtype":"float64","shape":[30]},"y":{"**ndarray**":"AAAAAAA6ukAAAAAAACi6QAAAAAAAG7pAAAAAAAAGukAAAAAAAPK5QAAAAAAA47lAAAAAAADYuUAAAAAAAMm5QAAAAAAAu7lAAAAAAACruUAAAAAAAJS5QAAAAAAAgLlAAAAAAABquUAAAAAAAFu5QAAAAAAARrlAAAAAAAA4uUAAAAAAACi5QAAAAAAAFblAAAAAAAD8uEAAAAAAAOq4QAAAAAAA2rhAAAAAAADFuEAAAAAAALK4QAAAAAAAprhAAAAAAACOuEAAAAAAAHm4QAAAAAAAZLhAAAAAAABOuEAAAAAAADm4QAAAAAAAIrhA","dtype":"float64","shape":[30]}},"id":"14848"}'

The data is received properly in the AJAX javascript but nothing is displayed on the graph. As I said previously, I believe there must be some extra processing done on the javascript side of things to properly receive the datetime variable but I have no idea what that would be. No errors on either the python or javascript side of things the plot simply just does not show any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have run in to a corner case interaction that evidently no-one has ever encountered before. For standalone HTML output, Bokeh performs a base64 encoding of CDS columns that are NumPy arrays or Pandas Series, because it is more performant than JSON processing arrays, *especially* nested arrays (e.g. for images). You can see these in your output as the objects with **`"ndarray"`** keys. Normally, the decoding is handled automatically by BokehJS for actual CDS objects that are serialized during `show`, etc.

But this interaction, where the data is consumed by `AjaxDataSource`, has a problem. The `AjaxDataSource` does *not* know about the base64 encoding, or know what to do with those **`"ndarray"`** objects. It expects plain JSON arrays of numbers in all cases.

Unfortunately, there is no parameter to `to_json_string`, or global setting or environment variable to suppress the base64 encoding (against my better judgment I was persuaded to remove it). So, my best suggestion to you for a workaround for now is to monkey-patch the function that controls whether the encoding happens:

```
In [12]: from bokeh.sampledata.perceptions import numberly

In [13]: from  bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

In [14]: import bokeh.util.serialization as s

In [15]: s.array_encoding_disabled = lambda x: True # PATCH HERE FORCES ENCODE OFF 

In [16]: source = ColumnDataSource(numberly)

In [17]: source.to_json_string(include_defaults=False)
```

You will notice the output now has none of those **`"ndarray"`** objects that are present in your output.

> Out[17]: '{"data":{"A couple":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,4,8,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2],"A few ":[3,3,5,5,3,3,3,3,4,5,4,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,7,10,3,3,5,3,3,3,5,3,3,3,4],"A lot":[20,12,15,15,50,10,9,50,30,16,80,50,25,10,10,10,100,20,20,10,10,12,20,20,10,9,25,10,12,14,47,10,2948,43,20,8,10,23,7,12,20,10,12,7,12,20],"Dozens":[30,24,30,30,48,36,36,50,36,36,36,36,36,48,12,24,36,36,12,24,36,48,60,12,24,36,24,36,36,30,36,36,24,12,50,36,12,40,36,24,24,36,36,60,120,36],"Fractions of":[0.15,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.01,0.5,4.0,0.5,0.2,4.0,0.5,0.33,0.2,0.25,0.25,0.1,1.0,0.1,1.0,0.01,0.1,15.0,0.25,3.0,0.1,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.1,2.0,0.4,0.5,10.0,0.5,0.1,3.0,0.4,33.0,0.5,0.1,50.0,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.1,100.0],"Hundreds of":[250,200,500,500,599,400,200,1000,500,300,300,200,300,400,350,200,3000,300,200,200,300,400,250,300,250,200,200,300,500,200,318,300,500,120,700,300,100,400,500,300,500,200,300,300,300,500],"Many":[12,50,25,25,5,20,7,20,20,25,7,50,10,60,8,10,30,9,8,10,10,40,25,20,25,10,25,20,5,7,8,20,1000,30,100,25,20,58,7,6,10,15,20,5,25,80],"Scores of":[80,40,500,500,100000,400,8,100,100,1000,30000,100,50,40,14,6,40,50,3,40,300,80,100,30,40,60,100,2000,60,200,67,40,50,25,100,100,100,40,40,300,1000,40,200,80,80,500],"Several":[7,10,4,4,5,7,3,10,8,8,4,8,7,7,4,4,7,5,10,2,5,6,7,8,4,7,10,5,7,7,4,8,7,5,8,4,5,6,4,7,10,10,5,7,5,5],"Some":[4,6,5,5,3,5,4,15,5,10,3,4,4,8,3,2,5,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,5,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,6,6,5,4,5,5,4,3,3,7],"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45]},"id":"1001"}'

I would suggest you file a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pulls) with all this information so that this situation with `AjaxDataSource` can be improved.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thank you so much. This makes what I was going through a lot more understandable. I will go ahead and add a bug report on the GitHub as you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad the answer was helpful! As a project maintainer it is helpful for SO questions to have accepted answers, so an accept would be appreciated.

Comment: I just hit the same use case tonight trying to stream some temperature data over to bokeh. I'll have to futz it with total seconds for the time being until a solution comes along. Anyone have a link to the github issue handy to reference here?

Comment: I don't think anyone ever made one. (So I would encourage you to make one)